# Favicon not displaying in IE on a file:// URL

Tags: html, http, internet-explorer-10, favicon

I'm trying to add a favicon to a (simple) HTML page. It has to work on Internet Explorer only, I don't care about other browsers.

```
<html>
<head>

<title>Test</title>
<!-- COMMENTS -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico"/>


</head>


<body>  

Favicon Test
<a href="favicon.ico" target="_blank">Download</a>

</body>
</html>
```

It doesn't work. I tried in order: /favicon.ico, the absolute path in this format \\SERVER\...\favicon.ico, an http://randomDomain.com/favicon.ico http link, Base64 encoding of the .ico file, Base64 of png file but any solution is actually working. I'm 100% sure the .ico file is well designed. I was wondering if this problem is related to the fact that the page is actually hosted on a system where is not running an HTTP server. In fact, if i try to click on the Download link and then I look at image properties, the result is this

[image: File protocol]
<sub>(source: [xomf.com](http://i.xomf.com/whxyc.jpg))</sub>

[image: HTTP protocol]
<sub>(source: [xomf.com](http://i.xomf.com/wzmgn.jpg))</sub>

Is there any solution? Consider that there wouldn't be a problem using an external http link but it doesn't work.

Many thanks

Comment: Perhaps the favicon is not getting loaded from a http location in a `file://` context for security reasons. Most browsers have stopped allowing links like that

Comment: That said, have you tried `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="file://<folder your page is in>/favicon.ico"/>` ? That would seem like the most obvious way, no?

Comment: As I said, I wouldn't mind to load it from a remote location, but it doesn't wanna work!

Comment: I don't mean a remote location, I mean the exact location your current page is in. Can you show the URL your page is on right now?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you previous comment. So in a file:// context http favicon won't work for security reasons... Understood. Yes, I tried to put the exact location (basically, I copypasted the URL of the first image). The page html and the ico file are in the same folder.

Comment: Can you show the URL your page is on right now?

Comment: \\CENTRAL\Share\machine\test.html

Comment: And you have tried pointing the favicon to `file:////CENTRAL/Share/machine/favicon.ico`? (Not sure about the `////` in the beginning, might be `///`, try both)

Comment: On second thought, it's probably pointless, since you've already tried the relative link, but you never know. It may be impossible to do at all due to some security restriction.

Comment: I'd try to clear the browser cache. You'd be sometimes surprised, which bugs the cache sometimes causes.

Comment: Nada... even after several cache update, nothing is working ;:P